# extending multiple classes to have columns from other entities is not working in nest JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nest

I'm working on a nest Project , where I have to extend my entity class to have common columns from other class.
BASEMODEL

```
import { Index, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

export class BaseModel {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string
}
```

AUDITMODEL

```
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { RequestContext } from "src/utils/req-ctx";
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

export class AuditModel {

    @Column({ name: "created_by", default: null })
    created_by: string

    @Column({ name: "modified_by", default: null })
    modified_by: string


    @BeforeInsert()
    setAuditsBeforeInsert() {
        console.log(RequestContext.currentRequest)
        if (RequestContext.currentRequest.currentUser) {
            this.created_by = this.modified_by = RequestContext.currentRequest.currentUser.name
        }
    }

    @BeforeUpdate()
    setAuditsBeforeUpdate() {
        if (RequestContext.currentRequest.currentUser) {
            this.modified_by = RequestContext.currentRequest.currentUser.name
        }
    }
}
```

USERMODEL

```
import { BaseModel } from 'src/base-models/base-model';
import { AuditModel } from 'src/base-models/audit-model';

function mixin(...classes: any[]): any {
  class MixedClass {}

  classes.forEach((clazz) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clazz.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      MixedClass.prototype[name] = clazz.prototype[name];
    });
  });

  return MixedClass;
}

@Entity()
@Unique(['email'])
export class Users extends mixin(BaseModel,AuditModel) {
//Other user attributes
}
```

I'm trying this approach, I wanted it in the same way, there are because there are some other models which extend some other mode with base model.

Can anyone please help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend the entity and the columns of the `baseClass` will be inherited by the `childClass` as the following ex:

```
export class MultiTenantEntity
{
  @ManyToOne(() => Tenant, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'tenant_id' })
  tenant: Tenant;
  @Column({ name: 'tenant_id', type: 'uuid' })
  tenantId: string;
}
    
@Entity()
export class Product extends MultiTenantEntity {
  @Column({ length: 255 })
  name: string;
    
  @Column({ length: 255, nullable: true })
  description: string;
}
```